# making REST calls to a service uploaded to heroku

Tags: java, rest, heroku, deployment, get

I made a simple RESTful web server in Java, using NetBeans. 
I deployed it into heroku along with a DB that the server is using.

My question is: 
I am trying to make REST calls to this server, but even if deploying it in localhost I can succesfully make a GET call on http://localhost:8080/Favorites/resources/allphotos,
when I try to make the same call on the same resource to the one deployed to heroku I get 404 not found error.
My deployed app URL is: https://aroundmefavorites.herokuapp.com/ and it's reachable, so my program is correctly deployed and running.
I am trying to make the call to : https://aroundmefavorites.herokuapp.com/resources/allphotos obviously.

Do you know how Heroku handles endpoints and how should I call them?

EDIT: I tried to run my app locally through the command heroku war:run and it is running but going on localhost:8080 tells me that my tomcat server is running, but no URI seems to be reachable (always 404). While deploying it locally through NetBeans everything run perfectly.

Comment: Have you tried running the app locally with either `heroku local` or `heroku war:run`? Can you reproduce the problem that way?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried both commands, but while I couldn't manage to make heroku local work, I tried with the heroku war:run -a --war <warpath>... the shell took the command and it says "running Favorites.war", it keeps saying things and at the end it says "Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]" and nothing happens, I can't write to the shell, I can't even select things to copy and paste here. Is the war actually running locally? If so, how should I try to call it? One thing I am noticing is that in one line it says "no global web.xml found"

Comment: That’s what is supposed to happen. Go to localhost:8080 in a browser while its running.

Comment: On localhost:8080 it says that my tomcat server is running, but for each URL I try to use for the GET, it always give me 404. I can't even reach the initial page that is running for the deployed app.